# Object to String using ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString() in JDK11

Tags: java, string, java-11

I am trying to convert an Object to String using ToStringBuilder.reflection.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object obj = "Hello";
    System.out.print(ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(obj));
}
```

The output in JDK 8 is:

```
java.lang.String@7ea987ac[value={H,e,l,l,o},hash=69609650]
```

The output in JDK 11 is:

```
java.lang.String@18ef96[value={72,101,108,108,111},coder=0,hash=69609650]
```

I understand in JDK 11 it prints the byte array as JDK 11 defines 'value' field in String class as a byte array (**private final byte[] value;**) compared to char[] in JDK 8. Is there anyway to print the String value as a char array in JDK 11 just like the output in JDK 8 above?

Comment: why not represent the object with a specific type `String`? and then it might be easier to perform `toCharArray` over it in both versions.

Comment: Be prepared to get no access to that array at all in a future version. What’s the point of getting that unreadable output instead of what calling `toString()` on `obj` will give you?

Answer (score 0):

By default is should be sufficient for a `java.lang.String` to call `toString()` to get the string value independently of the used JRE/JDK version.

Or use `toCharArray()` in combination with `Arrays.toString` if you want the char values:

```
String str = "test123äöüß@€";        
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str.toCharArray())); 
// Output: [t, e, s, t, 1, 2, 3, ä, ö, ü, ß, @, €]
```

If you prefer reflection (e.g. for other classes than `java.lang.String`) you can still access it via reflection and convert it back to a `String` and `char[]`:

```
String str = "test123äöüß@€";

Field valueField = String.class.getDeclaredField("value");
valueField.setAccessible(true);
byte[] bytearr = (byte[]) valueField.get(str);

// Get the used charset (since Java 9 this does not have to be UTF-16)
Field coderField = String.class.getDeclaredField("coder");
coderField.setAccessible(true);
byte coder = coderField.getByte(str);
Charset charset = coder == 0 ? StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1 : StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE;
    
String s = new String(bytearr, charset);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.toCharArray()));
```

This code was tested on a desktop PC with 64bit x86 CPU. On CPU's that are by default using big endian it may be `StandardCharsets.UTF_16BE` instead.

Comment: …and it may be iso-latin-1, depending on the content. Which is what the change to byte arrays was all about.

Comment: @Holger Correct, I have updated the code to reflect the used charset.

Comment: You can use `ByteOrder.nativeOrder() == ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN` (using `java.nio.ByteOrder`) to check which UTF16 encoding to use.